# instancing com object allowed in dllmain() / DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH?

Tags: c++, windows, com, instance, dllmain

Loading DLLs in in `DLLMAIN()`  / `DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH` may cause trouble. But may `COM Objects` be instanced using e.q. CoInitialize() / CoCreateInstance()?

**EDIT**: The question is:
Could creating COM instances cause similar errors like loading DLLs in this circumstances?
Loading DLLs an creating COM instances seem to me similar in a way.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure where you got that quote from, but it doesn't sound right.

You should never put any code of any significance into DllMain.  Especially code that invokes LoadLibrary. Many Windows APIs will call LoadLibrary under the hood, so it's best to avoid doing any complex initialization here.  Use a global C++ object (for it's constructor) or better yet, export a function for initialization.

CoCreateInstance for in-proc components ultimately will call LoadLibrary or one of its variants. It would not be wise to call this function in DllMain either.

Comment: Won't constructors for global objects be called in the context of DllMain?  (I can imagine how the runtime library could avoid doing that for globals in load-time DLLs, but don't see how it would be possible for globals in run-time DLLs.)

Comment: @HarryJohnston - I had probably though (naively) that CRT initialization, which initializes globals happens after DllMain, outside of the loader operations, and on the thread that called LoadLibrary.  I need to double-check some sources. I will update my answer appropriately.